# Control template not updating, why?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I have a button with a control template, when i click on the button, the text on th ebutton should change, but it doesn't. Here is the problem detailed:
My button is set up this way:

```
<Button x:Name="ElsoKonyv" Template="{DynamicResource KonyvButton}" 
Click="ElsoKonyv_Click" ></Button>
```

My ControlTemplate in the dictionary:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="KonyvButton" TargetType="Button" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="BlanchedAlmond">
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Cim}"></Label>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Szerzo}"></Label>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=KiadEv}"></Label>
    </StackPanel>

</ControlTemplate>
```

And here is my click event:

```
private void ElsoKonyv_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        konyvtar[0].KiadEv++;  
    }
```

KiadEv is an integer, which is displayed on the button. Ever click increases the value by one, but the displayed value does not change.Why is that?

Comment: Why are you using ControlTemplate to do this ? There is DataTemplate to format your data.

Comment: Also, have you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `KiadEv` property? Some more code on `konyvtar` would be useful

Comment: some more code plzz..